# Exponentiate a number N times in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, exponentiation

I want to write a function that can exponentiate a base number N times by a same exponent. For example, if I want to square a base number 2 three times, i.e. to calculate 2^2^2^2, the expected answer is 256. This seems trivial and I wrote the following recursive function:

```
def exponentiate_n_times(base, exponent, n):
    if n == 0:
        return base**exponent
    return exponentiate_n_times(base**exponent, exponent, n=n-1)
```

However, the output is incorrect:

```
print(exponentiate_n_times(2, 2, 3))
# 65536
```

Then I tried this in Python:

```
2**2**2**2
```

and it also returns

```
65536
```

This is very confusing to me because I was expecting 256.

I don't know what's wrong with my function. Can anyone suggest the right way to exponentiate a number N times?

Comment: 2^2^2^2 = 2 ^ (2 ^ (2 ^ 2)) = 2 ^ (2 ^4 ) = 2 ^ 16

Comment: `2**2**2**2` is parsed as `2**(2**(2**2)))`, rather than `((2**2)**2)**2` which is indeed 256.

Comment: "This is very confusing to me because I was expecting 256." I don't understand why. 65536 is the answer you get following the normal mathematical rules. Please see for example https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/439075/incorrect-notation-in-math .

Comment: If you want to repeatedly do the same thing, a loop is generally a better idea than recursion.

Comment: @jasonharper I thought arithmetic operations always start from left to right (assuming no parentheses and same operation)?

Comment: @Shaun Han: the ```**``` operator binds from right to left.

Comment: See [operator precedence](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#operator-precedence)

Comment: ``return exponentiate_n_times(base**exponent, exponent, n=n-1)`` should be ``return exponentiate_n_times(base, exponent, n=n-1)**exponent``. The base case should be ``base`` for ``n==1``.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So you want to calculate `base ** (exponent ** n)`, and since the operator `**` already binds right to left, we can skip the brackets:

```
def exponentiate_n_times(base, exponent, n):
    return base ** exponent ** n

exponentiate_n_times(2, 2, 3) # 256
exponentiate_n_times(3, 2, 3) # 6561
exponentiate_n_times(3, 3, 3) # 7625597484987
```